# Por qué no funciona esta condición dentro de un bucle en python?

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles

estoy aprendiendo a programar y estoy teniendo problemas con un codigo.
............................................................................................

Yo quisiera que el codigo se ejecute en bucle (tipo while), pero cuando llegue a las lineas donde tengo unos asserts (al final) se regrese al inicio si cualquiera de los dos assert son verdaderos, y se siga ejecutando el bucle otra vez.

Pero no se que estoy haciendo mal, porque no estoy pudiendo lograr lo que quiero..

aqui les dejo el codigo

```
# ------------- Page 1 --------------------------
while True:
    assert request_rejected_message not in browser.page_source, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") + " " + request_rejected_message
    time.sleep(random.randint(8,15))

    # Select Provincia
    select = Select(browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'form'))
    select.select_by_visible_text(city)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    # Click submit
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btnAceptar')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)

    # ------------- Page 2 --------------------------
    assert request_rejected_message not in browser.page_source, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") + " " + request_rejected_message
    time.sleep(random.randint(8,15))

    # Select Provincia
    select = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID, "sede"))
    select.select_by_visible_text(office)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    # Select document
    select = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID, "tramiteGrupo[0]"))
    select.select_by_value(document_value)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    # Click submit
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btnAceptar')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)

    # ------------- Page 3 --------------------------
    assert request_rejected_message not in browser.page_source, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") + " " + request_rejected_message
    time.sleep(random.randint(8,15))

    # Click submit
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btnEntrar')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)

    # ------------- Page 4 --------------------------
    assert request_rejected_message not in browser.page_source, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") + " " + request_rejected_message
    time.sleep(random.randint(8,25))

    # Radio Button Click
    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'rdbTipoDocPas').click()

    time.sleep(random.randint(10,15))

    # Send passport id
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "txtIdCitado")
    element.send_keys(passport)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    # Send complete name
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "txtDesCitado")
    element.send_keys(full_name)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    # Send byear id
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "txtAnnoCitado")
    element.send_keys(byear)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    # Select country
    select = Select(browser.find_element(By.ID, 'txtPaisNac'))
    select.select_by_visible_text(country)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3,10))

    # Click submit
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btnEnviar')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)

    # ------------- Page 5 --------------------------
    assert request_rejected_message not in browser.page_source, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") + " " + request_rejected_message
    time.sleep(random.randint(8,15))

    # Click submit
    element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btnEnviar')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)



    # ------------- Page 6 --------------------------

    time.sleep(random.randint(8,15))

    if assert "En este momento no hay citas disponibles" not in browser.page_source:
        element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btnSalir')
        browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
    else:
        if assert request_rejected_message not in browser.page_source, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") + " " + request_rejected_message:
            element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'btnSalir')
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Los asserts estan diseñados para generar un error simple. Te conviene mas usar condicionales

Comment: Los [assert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41721518/1545868) son una herramienta útil para generar errores intencionales y de esta forma poder debuguear o testear el proyecto. Si no sabes qué estás haciendo, usa condicionales (if/while) o excepciones (try - except)

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres comprobar si una condición es cierta mediante un `if` basta que escribas:

```
if condicion:
   codigo a ejecutar en caso de que sea cierta
```

El `assert` es otra cosa, aunque superficialmente se parece ya que también pones `assert condicion`, pero el cometido es muy diferente:

- Si la condición tras `assert` es falsa, se producirá una **excepción** que abortará el programa (dudo que sea eso lo que querías)
- Si la condición tras el `assert` es cierta, no ocurrirá nada.
- `assert condicion` no es una expresión, sino una sentencia. Esto quiere decir que no puede aparecer formando parte de otra sentencia. Por ejemplo no es válido escribir `print(assert 3==3)`, ni tampoco `resultado = assert 3==3` y por tanto tampoco `if assert 3==3`

En general, es muy raro utilizar o ver un `assert` formando parte de un código. Son más comunes formando parte de los frameworks de testing, para comprobar si el resultado devuelto por una función es el que se espera. Por ejemplo:

```
def test_raiz_cuadrada():
    assert raiz_cuadrada(25) == 5.0
```

Si la función retorna efectivamente 5.0 no ocurre nada y se dice que el test *pasa*. Si en cambio retorna otra cosa, se producirá una excepción y por tanto el test *falla*. Los frameworks de testing suelen capturar esas excepciones para al final proporcionar informes de qué tests han pasado y cuáles han fallado.

En ocasiones se usa también `assert` dentro del código para asegurarse de que *jamás* se da cierta condición que sabemos que nunca debe darse. Si se diera sería un bug y el programa debería ser abortado. Así se podría escribir `assert not condicion_que_nunca_deberia_ocurrir`. Pero como digo es poco frecuente, y es más común utilizar condicionales "normales" y si acaso elevar manualmente las excepciones con `raise` (para así poder elevar una excepción más apropiada).

Por ejemplo, este código no es muy adecuado:

```
assert x != 0, "La x vale cero y es un valor prohibido"
```

si ejecutas este código siendo `x=0`, la condición `x !=0` será falsa, y se elevará una excepción con el mensaje entre comillas. El programa abortaría así:

```
AssertionError: La x vale cero y es un valor prohibido
```

Como ves, la excepción elevada es `AssertionError`, pero para este caso resulta más adecuado elevar una `ValueError` cosa que no puede hacerse con `assert`, pero sí de este otro modo:

```
if x==0:
   raise ValueError("La x vale cero y es un valor prohibido")
```

En este caso el programa abortaría con el mensaje:

```
ValueError: La x vale cero y es un valor prohibido
```

Esto no sólo afecta al mensaje en caso de aborto, sino que también hace más lógico para los usuarios de tu función el capturar la excepción correcta. Así, quien llama a tu función, en previsión de que genere un `ValueError` podría escribir:

```
try:
   llamada_a_tu_funcion()
except ValueError as e:
   print(f"Algo ha ido mal, un valor no válido. {e}")
```